# Reloading modules with importlib in IPython

Tags: python, ipython, reload, interactive, python-importlib

I'm confused by the behaviour of `importlib` in the interactive IPython shell. When I run:

```
import importlib.reload as ilrel
```

I get the error `ImportError: No module named 'importlib.reload'`. This is exactly how I import other modules, such as `matplotlib.pyplot`.

Currently I've been simply importing `importlib` alone, then using `importlib.reload(<module name>)`. This isn't a major issue but why does the first method not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `reload` is not a module, it's a function within the `importlib` module. There is nothing specific about importlib; this is how imports work for all modules.

If you just want the function itself, you can do `from importlib import reload`.

Note also that this function is only available in Python 3.4+.

Comment: and if you use Daniel's suggested `from importlib import reload` then you call the function as `reload(<module name>)` instead of `importlib.reload(<module name>)`